# Operator precedence in Java not according to Java specification

Tags: java, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

```
     import java.util.*;
     class OperatorPrecedenceExp
     {
        public static void main(String[] args)
         {

          int e=10;
          sum=++e+e--;//e-- should b evaluated first
          System.out.println("sum="+sum);
         } 
     }
```

The above code prints `sum=22`. But according to Java specification `e--` should be evaluated before `++e`.  So result should `sum=20` instead of `sum=22`.

Comment: "*according to java specification `e--` should be evaluated before `++e`*" => do you have a reference? Expressions are generally evaluated left to right...

Comment: Of all the problems Java has, this seems like a pretty trivial one

Comment: As @assylias points out, your entire question appears to be based on a faulty premise.

Answer (score 1):

When you say *`e--` should be evaluated first*,

> ```
> sum=++e+e--;//e-- should be evaluated first
> ```

you must be incorrect. For one thing `e--` doesn't change `e` until the next statement (that is the *post* in [post-decrement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators)). Next, if you change your code to,

```
int sum = ++e + --e;
System.out.printf("sum=%d%n", sum);
```

You will see that first `e` is pre-incremented then added to a pre-decrement of `e` (in that order) because the sum is

```
21
```

Your expected result (20) can be obtained with

```
int e = 11;
int sum = --e + e++;
System.out.printf("sum=%d%n", sum);
```

or

```
int e = 9;
int sum = ++e + e--;
System.out.printf("sum=%d%n", sum);
```

I hope that helps.

**Edit**

Per your [Java Tutorials link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html),

> *All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.*

You can't just skim the table.

Comment: ,@assylias ,@Oli Charlesworth click this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)  u r not getting my question.. according to Java specification operator precedence , postfix should be evaluated before prefix operator, so accordingly "e--" should be evaluated before "e++"...plz everybody see the link before commenting..

Comment: @RanjitSran Edited to address your link, the Java Tutorials are not the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html).